# How to define MSB or LSB of a binary number

Tags: math-mode, accents

I have bit string and would like to write MSB (short for Most Significant Bit) over the first bit and LSB (short for Least Significant Bit) over top of the last bit. How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A combination of `\overset` and `\substack` lets you position the labels and the arrows above the respective digits. To assure that the presence of the labels doesn't affect the spacing of the digits, use `\mathclap`. If you have many such cases, it's useful to define a macro that takes two arguments -- the label and the digit.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % to access \overset, \substack, \mathclap, and \text macros
\newcommand\bitpos[2]{%
    \overset{\substack{\mathclap{\text{\tiny #1}}\\ \downarrow}}{#2}}
\begin{document}
$\bitpos{MSB}{1}001100\bitpos{LSB}{1}$
\end{document}
```

*Addendum*: The code shown above assumes that `\bitpos` will be used in math mode. If that's not necessarily the case, just provide an `\ensuremath{...}` wrapper instruction as well, i.e., define `\bitpos` as follows:

```
\newcommand\bitpos[2]{%
    \ensuremath{\overset{\substack{\mathclap{\text{\tiny #1}}\\ \downarrow}}{#2}}}
```

Comment: If you need to make the labels (MSB, LSB) more compact, you could try using `\textsf` instead of `\text` in the definition of `\bitpos`.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps a bit longer than expected, but, hey, you get automatic conversion and optional removal of the labels.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\bits}{O{}m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { chekooo/bits } { #1 }
  \chekooo_bits:n { #2 }
  \group_end:
 }

\keys_define:nn { chekooo/bits }
 {
  convert .bool_set:N = \l_chekooo_convert_bool,
  convert .initial:n  = false,
  convert .default:n  = true,
  nosb    .bool_set:N = \l_chekooo_show_bool,
  nosb    .initial:n  = false,
  nosb    .default:n  = true,
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \chekooo_bits:n
 {
  \bool_if:NTF \l_chekooo_convert_bool
   {
    \chekooo_process:f { \int_to_bin:n { #1 } }
   }
   {
    \chekooo_process:n { #1 }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \chekooo_process:n
 {
  \bool_if:NTF \l_chekooo_show_bool
   {
    #1
   }
   {
    \chekooo_bits_show:n { #1 }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \chekooo_process:n { f }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \chekooo_bits_show:n
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { \tl_count:n { #1 } < 2 }
   {
    #1
   }
   {
    \__chekooo_bits_show:n { #1 }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__chekooo_bits_show:n
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__chekooo_bits_seq { } { #1 }
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l__chekooo_bits_seq \l__chekoo_msb_tl
  \seq_pop_right:NN \l__chekooo_bits_seq \l__chekoo_lsb_tl
  \mspace{10mu} % for the M
  \overset
   {
    \substack{\scriptscriptstyle\hidewidth\mathrm{MSB}\hidewidth\\\downarrow}
   }
   {\l__chekoo_msb_tl}
  \mspace{8mu}
  \seq_use:Nn \l__chekooo_bits_seq { \mspace{8mu} }
  \mspace{8mu}
  \overset
   {
    \substack{\scriptscriptstyle\hidewidth\mathrm{LSB}\hidewidth\\\downarrow}
   }
   {\l__chekoo_lsb_tl}
  \mspace{8mu}
 }

\seq_new:N \l__chekooo_bits_seq
\tl_new:N \l__chekoo_msb_tl
\tl_new:N \l__chekoo_lsb_tl

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
\bits{1001}+
\bits[nosb]{1001}+
\bits[convert]{42}+
\bits[convert,nosb]{42}
\]
\[
\bits{0}+\bits{1}+\bits{10}+\bits{11}+\bits{100}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]